# how do I run jruby in jenkins on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, rvm, jruby

I'm having an issue with executing a bash script from within jenkins.  I have the shell command checked and my inputs are as follows:

```
rvm use jruby-1.7.4
export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
jruby -S cucumber
```

FYI: those 3 commands are exactly what I type in the terminal when launching cucumber outside of Jenkins.

When I execute those commands, this is my output

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson7305254619895710829.sh
+ rvm use jruby-1.7.4
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

+ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
+ jruby -S cucumber
/home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson7305254619895710829.sh: 4: /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson7305254619895710829.sh: jruby: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So I execute with the /bin/bash --login as the first command to my script and I still get

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson7981126593924329573.sh
+ /bin/bash --login
+ rvm use jruby-1.7.4
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

+ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
+ jruby -S cucumber
/home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson7981126593924329573.sh: 5: /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson7981126593924329573.sh: jruby: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

So I tried using the RVM plugin and setting it to use jruby 1.7.4 and this is the result

```
Capturing environment variables produced by 'rvm use jruby-1.7.4'
$ bash -c export
$ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
$ bash -c "test -f /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
[workspace] $ bash -c " source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create jruby-1.7.4 && export > rvm.env"
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson661746741998327634.sh
+ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
+ jruby -S cucumber
/home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson661746741998327634.sh: 3: /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson661746741998327634.sh: jruby: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

reload bashrc or bash_profile to make sure rvm is getting loaded

```
/bin/bash --login
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_profile
rvm use jruby-1.7.4
```

my bashrc has this

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

bash_profile has this

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```